# Can't move any applications to SD Card- "Couldn't Move App" error

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-s, system-error, internal-sd

I'm trying to move any application that I install to my SD card (Nexus S, so its technically internal storage) and regardless of what I choose, I get a

```
"Couldn't Move App"
```

error. I fired up logcat and got the following output:

```
 I/DefContainer( 1273): Copied data/app/de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1.apk to /mnt/asec/de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1/pkg.apk
 D/VoldCmdListener(   81): asec finalize de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
 E/Vold    (   81): Failed to chmod /mnt/asec/de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1 (Read-only file system)
 E/Vold    (   81): ASEC finalize mount failed (Read-only file system)
 W/Vold    (   81): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30
 I/PackageHelper( 1273): Failed to finalize container  e.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
 I/PackageHelper( 1273): Forcibly destroying container de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
 D/dalvikvm(  250): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
 E/DefContainer( 1273): Failed to finalize de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1 at path /mnt/asec/de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
 D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_EXPLICIT freed 48K, 26% free 14596K/19591K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 64ms
 D/VoldCmdListener(   81): asec destroy de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1 force
 I/PackageHelper(  250): Forcibly destroying container de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
 D/dalvikvm(  250): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
 W/ActivityManager(  250): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/app/de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1.apk
 D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 26% free 14595K/19591K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 63ms
 D/VoldCmdListener(   81): asec destroy de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1 force
 E/Vold    (   81): Couldn't find ASEC de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
 I/PackageHelper(  250): Failed to destroy container de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
 I/PackageHelper(  250): Forcibly destroying container de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
 D/dalvikvm(  250): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
 D/dalvikvm(  250): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 26% free 14594K/19591K, paused 3ms+8ms, total 69ms
 I/PackageHelper(  250): Failed to destroy container de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
 D/VoldCmdListener(   81): asec destroy de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1 force
 E/Vold    (   81): Couldn't find ASEC de.joergjahnke.gameboy.android.free-1
```

It seems to be a permissions issue of some kind. I've tried booting into CWM and resetting permissions, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Even re-formatting the storage doesn't seem to do anything. If anyone has any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: 4.1 hides paid pps by default using some app2sd technology, maybe some of this broke your current app2sd program. Which are you using? Internal, 3rd party,...?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using 3rd party apps to test this (ones downloaded from the marketplace). I'm not trying to migrate any internal apps, only ones that claim that they can be moved.

Comment: I was just wondering if that 3rd party app is broken on JB